# How to capture unhandled exceptions on Windows Services?

Tags: .net, exception, windows-services, unhandled-exception

I use [`AppDomain.UnhandledException` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) to capture unhandled exceptions on WPF, Console and WinForms apps.

But the same code isn't working on Windows Services. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my answer added to the [linked SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5117790/68571).

There are a number of places in your service code where a thrown exception will not be "unhandled" even if you don't handle it, because the base class does so before it reaches the AppDomain's default handler.