# CurrentDomain.UnhandledException is not being thrown in Windows Service

Tags: c#, unhandled-exception

I've setup the UnhandledException to log any exceptions before my service crashes.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(unhandledException);
```

I'm testing this by throwing and unhandled exception.

```
throw new Exception("TestExcepion");

private void unhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // Logs to Log4Net but its not reaching here.
    Log.Info("Unhandled Exception: " + (e.ExceptionObject as Exception).ToString());
}
```

I'm attempting to log this within my `unhandledException` method using Log4Net but im getting nothing.

Why isn't the exception being caught?

Comment: Post more of your code here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably that your throwing code is before use set `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` or because you put it in `OnStart` method

Second option is because it is `ThreadException`.

Bot above problems were discussed before in following threads:

1. [How can I set up .NET UnhandledException handling in a Windows service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456819/how-can-i-set-up-net-unhandledexception-handling-in-a-windows-service)
2. [Global exception handler for windows services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682128/global-exception-handler-for-windows-services)

Comment: Bingo. I am putting it in the OnStart method. Thanks.

Comment: `ThreadException` is specific to Windows Forms and doesn't apply to Windows Services (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2014684/8479).