# what is dsac.exe.config

Tags: windows-services

I have a windows service installed on a machine running Windows 2008 which automatically stops every night between 2300-0100 hrs.
In the eventviewer I get "dsac.exe.config" file changed. Apart from this I also get the below error in event viewer:

> The description for Event ID 1001 from
>   source Windows Error Reporting cannot
>   be found. Either the component that
>   raises this event is not installed on
>   your local computer or the
>   installation is corrupted. You can
>   install or repair the component on the
>   local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another
>   computer, the display information had
>   to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included
>   with the event:
>
> 0 CLR20r3 Not available 0
>   wsbestfarefinder.exe
>   337.0.0.0 4d8b67b0 Ttl.BestFareFinder.Harvester
>   337.0.0.0 4d8b67af 301 6 System.TypeInitialization
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_wsbestfarefinder_74e68497d40658e979de885388289e269c39c_c41e675c
>   0 9a6e7446-661e-11e0-9ac4-005056bc2f52
>   4
>
> The handle is invalid

Answer (score 1):

Based on [KB article 2462585](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2462585),

> Active Directory Administrative Center (Dsac.exe) to manage Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS) objects

That suggests that between those times, something is changing the `.config` file for `dsac.exe`. Whether this is relevant to your service or not is something that I suspect is unlikely. You can try to determine this though.

In your development/test/staging environment (you do have one, or all of those, right? :) start your service running and then **change the `dsac.exe.config` file**. Does this cause your service to stop? If yes, work out what's causing it to be changed in your production environment.

All that said, I **don't** think the change to `dsac.exe.config` is the issue, or at best it's a symptom and not the cause Your service is encountering an exception, specifically a [`TypeInitializationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typeinitializationexception.aspx) at some point in the night. You need to improve your logging and exception handling to get to the root cause of this. Start by hooking the [AppDomain.UnhandledException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682128/global-exception-handler-for-windows-services) event, logging any exceptions and ensuring that you ship `.pdb` files with your service.