# Internal Error in .NET Runtime?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Application Crashes With “Internal Error In The .NET Runtime”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367664/application-crashes-with-internal-error-in-the-net-runtime)

I have a Windows service that runs 24x7. On a regular interval the service will communicate with a SQL Server to process some data. On occasion, the SQL communication will time out. All the code that handles this is in a try/catch block. Yet, my service is still brought down. When I check the Event Log on the box running my service, I see the following error:

**"The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 66587CB5 (664E0000) with exit code 80131506".**

Is this really an error in the .NET framework bringing my service down, or is this in response to my SQL timeout error?

I'm using .NET 4.

Thanks very much.

Comment: See this question, the problem is probably some unmanaged code.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367664/application-crashes-with-internal-error-in-the-net-runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this really an error in the .NET framework bringing my service down, or is this in response to 
>   my SQL timeout error?

This can not be answered. It is a framework error, buti t could be occuring due to an error in unmanaged (!) code in a database driver. If the database is SQL Server, this is highly unlikely - if it is oracle, there are significant bugs the drivers ;) In not managed code.

It can NOT be the result of a managed code issue unless a runtime issue exists - the whole sense of pure managed code is that the runtime integrity is isolated. Well, one reason.

I would point my fingers at either unmanaged code - or defective RAM.

Answer (score 3):

Naturally you'd like some more error logging - we had something very similar with one of our sites, although we were catching the errors globally (global.asax), there are some exceptions (thread abort, being one) that will circumvent normal error handling.

Perhaps [this question on global exception handling in Windows Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682128/global-exception-handler-for-windows-services) might be helpful in catching/getting more info?