# How to Handle WCF Async Exceptions in Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, exception, windows-services

I want to make an async call to a function in my windows service but I want to keep the service running without crashing when an exception happens from the async call.

I saw some posts where I would need to use `await` but won't this make the call behave like synchronous calls do? I don't need to wait for the result of the WCF to be sent to me but I can only make changes to the windows service not the WCF web service so I can't do something like

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
void PrintString(string message);
```

Is there a way to handle all WCF-caused exceptions in something like a try-catch or a global exception handler to keep my windows service from crashing?

Will the `CurrentDomain_UnhandledException` (saw this from the question linked below)  catch the exception? If yes, would my windows service continue to run normally?

**
[Global exception handler for windows services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682128/global-exception-handler-for-windows-services)